# Problem sending Vuejs Array with Axios Post

Tags: javascript, php, post, axios, vuejs3

I'm trying to pass to my php server a request with some values, using axios.
values contain a string variable and an array.

The console log before axios contain correctly all the data, but when I recive everything in php, I lose the array data, that become empty, and I have just the string.

```
var params = {
          request: "INSERIMENTO_GARA"             
        }
        params.valori = Object.assign([],this.myRace),
        console.log(params);
        axios.post('../server/post.php',params, {
          headers: {
            Accept: "application/json",
            "Content-Type": "application/json;charset=UTF-8",
          },
        })              
        .then((response) => {
          console.log(response.data);
        })
        .catch((error) =>{
            console.log(error)
        })
```

On server side I simply:

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *");
header("Content-Type: application/json");

$body = file_get_contents('php://input');
echo $body;
die();
```

These are the console log before the axios request and of the response:

> {request: 'INSERIMENTO_GARA', valori: Array(0)} request:
> "INSERIMENTO_GARA" valori: [id: 0, nome: 'ciao', data: '2022-01-01',
> dist: '10', org: '11', …] [[Prototype]]: Object
>
> {request: 'INSERIMENTO_GARA', valori: Array(0)} request:
> "INSERIMENTO_GARA" valori: [] [[Prototype]]: Object

Really don't understand the issue.

Comment: is `this.myRace` and Array or an Object? you're sending JSON, so `$body;` will be JSON

Comment: console.log(typeof(this.myRace)) return an Object.
I read that Vue js convert all array in Object

Comment: `console.log(typeof [])` also outpus Object - so, you haven't actually determined anything - *I read that Vue js convert all array in Object* converts the arrays in an object to what?

Comment: it calls proxy object, i don't know exactly, i'm a newbie